# Removing values from a 3D array of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D array of indices generated from `np.argsort`, sorted by the 0-th axis, so that each column is the sorting index. However, I want to drop some values from this array, say 0. Of course, I can remove the 0-th slice then sort again, but I need to repeat this sort for many times and each time I need to remove some different values, so I would like to see if there is a more efficient way to generate the array. I think this problem is the same as shifting the `NaN` value along `axis=0` to the end.

### Example

Consider the following 3D array of sorting indices. Notice that along `axis=0` the array has unique values.

```
arr = np.array(
  [[[0, 0],
    [1, 2]],

   [[1, 2],
    [0, 1]],

   [[2, 1],
    [2, 0]]] 
)
```

Suppose I would like to remove the value `0` from it. The result would look like

```
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[2, 1],
        [2, 1]]])
```

### What I've tried

I tried removing the values using `np.where` and then `reshape` the array, but it is different from the expected array.

```
>>> arr[np.where(arr != 0)]
array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])

>>> arr[np.where(arr != 0)].reshape(-1, 2, 2)
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 2],
        [1, 2]]])
```

---

### Explanation of output

In consider `arr[:, 1, 0] = [1, 0, 2]`. After dropping 0, the new array is `[1, 2]`. Therefore `new_arr[:, 1, 0] = [1, 2]`.

Comment: Are you sure there is always a consistent number of rows with 0 to yield the correct shape after removing them?

Comment: Why [2, 1] is repeated in the output?

Comment: I was just wondering the same ;)

Comment: @mozway I am sure there is since the original index are generated through `np.argsort`. The result I expected is the same as dropping the 0-th slice then sorting it again.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I have edited my post to explain how the array is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that you can specify the axis order in `np.transpose`, and I came up with a solution with that.

### Solution

```
>>> arr_t = np.transpose(arr, (1, 2, 0))
>>> arr_dp = arr_t[arr_t != 0]
>>> arr_dp_rs = arr_dp.reshape(arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2], -1)
>>> new_arr = np.transpose(arr_dp_rs, (2, 0 ,1))
>>> new_arr
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[2, 1],
        [2, 1]]])
```

### Explanation

We first transpose `arr` so the 0-th axis is the inner most axis. This ensures after subsetting, the values are ordered in the 0-th axis.

```
>>> arr_t = np.transpose(arr, (1, 2, 0))
>>> arr_t
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 2, 1]],

       [[1, 0, 2],
        [2, 1, 0]]])

>>> arr_dp = arr_t[arr_t != 0]
>>> arr_dp
array([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1])
```

Now the values are in the desired order but along the 0-th axis, we reshape it then swap the axis again.

```
arr_dp_rs = arr_dp.reshape(arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2], -1)
arr_dp_rs
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 1]],

       [[1, 2],
        [2, 1]]])

new_arr = np.transpose(arr_dp_rs, (2, 0 ,1))
new_arr
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[2, 1],
        [2, 1]]])
```